# re-projection error calculation in camera calibration opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration, reprojection-error

The code below is the part of camera calibration from OpenCV. I just want to change a bit: the variable `err` is calculated using the Euclidean distance formula `sqrt(x-coordinate diff^2+y-coordinate diff^2)`, but I want to consider only the x-coordinate diff. so I have re-written it has

```
err = sqrt((imagePoints[i].x - imagePoints2.x) ^ 2);
```

However, I am getting error since I could not access the x co-ordinate values of vector of `imagePoints[i]` & `imagepoints2`.

Can somebody help in re-writing the variable `err` considering only the x co-ordinate delta?

```
static double computeReprojectionErrors(
    const vector<vector<Point3f> >& objectPoints,
    const vector<vector<Point2f> >& imagePoints,
    const vector<Mat>& rvecs, const vector<Mat>& tvecs,
    const Mat& cameraMatrix, const Mat& distCoeffs,
    vector<float>& perViewErrors, bool fisheye)
{

    vector<Point2f> imagePoints2;
    size_t totalPoints = 0;
    double totalErr = 0, err;
    perViewErrors.resize(objectPoints.size());

    for (size_t i = 0; i < objectPoints.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (fisheye)
        {
            fisheye::projectPoints(objectPoints[i], imagePoints2, rvecs[i],            tvecs[i], cameraMatrix,  distCoeffs);
        }
        else
        {
            projectPoints(objectPoints[i], rvecs[i], tvecs[i], cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, imagePoints2);
        }
        err = norm(imagePoints[i], imagePoints2, NORM_L2);

        size_t n = objectPoints[i].size();
        perViewErrors[i] = (float)std::sqrt(err*err / n);
        totalErr += err*err;
        totalPoints += n;
    }

    return std::sqrt(totalErr / totalPoints);
}
```

Comment: please elaborate more, what is the error being thrown ?

Comment: I did not compile it but it was showing as red line. when i wrote it has err = sqrt((imagePoints[i].x-imagePoints2.x)^2). I am not sure of how to address the x-coordinate of imagepoints since it is vector of vectors of 2-D points.